# dynamic pivot sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I am trying to select data from a customers table, a contract spend table, and a contract name table.  My tables look something like this

```
Customers
CustomerID  CustomerName  Address          etc
1           "ABC Corp"   "123 Here Ave"
2           "Acme Corp"  "101 Lets Ave"

ContractTypes
ContractTypeID ContractName
1              "Website Hosting"
2              "Domain Hosting"
3              "Email Hosting"

ServiceSpend
ServiceSpendID  ContractTypeID  CustomerID  Spend
1               2               1           5.99
2               1               1           5.99
3               1               2           9.99
```

I would like to produce the following table

```
CustomerID CustomerName Address         DomainHosting WebsiteHosting
1          "ABC Corp"   "123 Here Ave"  9.99          5.99
```

Currently I have the following sql statement which works but I need to be able to define the columns dynamically as we need to be able to add additional contract names to the database and still report on the customer spend

```
select *
from 
(
SELECT        
Customers.CustomerID, Customers.ContactName, Customers.Address,                              ContractTypes.ContractName AS ContractName, ServiceSpend.Spend
FROM            
Customers INNER JOIN
ServiceSpend ON Customers.CustomerID = ServiceSpend.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
ContractTypes ON ServiceSpend.ContractTypeID = ContractTypes.ContractTypeID
) src
pivot
(
sum(spend)
    for ContractName in ([Website Hosting],[Domain Hosting])) piv;
```

Does anyone know how I might add my columns dynamically

Comment: I don't think that you need a pivot here, why not just do a group by and use SUM to total the spend field?

Comment: How would I do that? would that create columns for the list of ContractNames i have?

Comment: Looking back at my question I think I have made a mistake, I would like to produce a table like this 

`CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, Domain Hosting, Website Hosting
1, "ABC Corp", "123 Here Ave", 9.99, 5.99`

Comment: That's still CASE aggregation. For example, `ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ContractTypes.ContractName = 'Website Hosting' THEN Spend END), 0) AS [Website Hosting]` in your select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql to construct the columns for your output:

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(1000) = STUFF((
    SELECT ',[' + ContactName + ']'
    FROM ContactTypes
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(1000) = '
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT        
            Customers.CustomerID,
            Customers.ContactName,
            Customers.Address,
            ContractTypes.ContractName,
            ServiceSpend.Spend
        FROM Customers
            INNER JOIN ServiceSpend
                ON Customers.CustomerID = ServiceSpend.CustomerID 
            INNER JOIN ContractTypes
                ON ServiceSpend.ContractTypeID = ContractTypes.ContractTypeID
        ) SRC
        PIVOT (SUM(Spend) FOR ContractName IN (' + @Columns + ')) piv;'
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Comment: **1)** Personally I prefer `STUFF(...,1,1,'')` to remove the leading comma. **2)** Setting the column `AS [text()]` isn't needed since the column has no name.

Comment: Good points...that was the way I was told to do this long ago and not sure why I hadn't questioned it since :) `STUFF` is way better for a lot of reasons. Thanks for the suggestions @TT